# Exported model not transferring with UV Wrap to Unity

Tags: mesh, uv, export, unity

I'm fairly new to unity so my apologies as I try to work this out.

I finished a model in blender that contains a few objects and uv wraps:[image]

When I load up the obj or fbx export of the entire project it shows up normally with everything attached:

[image]

However upon putting the model into unity, the object mesh will only show up and I can't find how to exporting everything as is.

This may be more of a unity problem but I thought I'd try here

Again, thank you for your patience and help ^_^